# Properly scale random movement in simulation with variable time delta

Tags: python, simulation

I want to write a simulation of a particle moving in 1D. The simulation has the following parameters:

- `max_speed`: the max speed the particle can obtain (in meters/second)
- `delta`: the time interval between two simulation steps (in seconds)
- `iters`: the number of steps to run the simulation

Below is an example of a working simulation. It returns two lists of values: one for the particle's position at each time step, and one for the corresponding seconds at each time step.

```
import random

def simulate_particle(max_speed, delta, iters):
    current_position = 0
    positions = [current_position]
    seconds = [0]
    for frame in range(1, iters+1):
        max_distance_possible = max_speed * delta
        current_position += max_distance_possible * random.uniform(-1, 1)
        positions.append(current_position)
        seconds.append(frame * delta)
    return positions, seconds
```

As you can see, the particle's position at the next frame is determined by:

- calculating the max distance possible that the particle is able to travel between two frames (taking into account the `max_speed` and `delta` parameters)
- multiplying this value by a value sampled from an uniform distribution over [-1, 1] (in order to add some randomness)

The issue here is that **the particle movement becomes tied to the `delta` parameter**. Since larger `delta`s allow for a larger max distance, it becomes easier for particles in simulations with large `delta`s to move further away from the starting position.

Here's a graphical representation of this issue:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for delta, iters, color in zip(
    [600, 60, 6],  # decreasing deltas
    [10, 100, 1000],  # larger number of iterations to achieve same end time
    ['blue', 'orange', 'green'],
):
    for repeat in range(50):  # run simulations 50 times for each delta
        ys, xs = simulate_particle(max_speed=5, delta=delta, iters=iters)
        label = f'{delta=}, {iters=}' if repeat == 0 else None
        plt.plot(xs, ys, color=color, label=label)

plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
plt.ylabel('Position')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

output:
[image]

I understand *why* this happens: It's much harder to reach extreme values when sampling many times from a narrow distribution, compared to sampling a few times from a broader one.

My question is **how do I fix this?** Is there some kind of normalization I can do? I tried changing the uniform distribution to other distributions (e.g. gaussian), but eventually the same effect happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main thing that you are running into is that composing multiple random runs headlong into the [Central Limit Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem). Namely, as you have seen, when you add up multiple uniform draws, you approach a normal distribution in the final particle locations rather than a single larger uniform distribution. Drawing from the uniform distribution in order to skip timesteps means that you are going to be effectively sampling from a distribution with much larger shoulders than you should. Hence the blue lines blowing up.

To fix this, you should figure out what your true fundamental timestep `delta0` is and run with that. If you want to speed up by some factor, then you should draw from the [Irwin–Hall distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution), and scale & shift that draw by the same transformation you would make to a [0, 1] uniform distribution to get it in the [-1, 1] range. And whether you speed up or not, you should change your `max_distance_possible` equation to rely on the fundamental timestep.

So for example, here's a bit of pseudocode to replace the main loop:

```py
delta0 = 1
speedupfactor = 10
delta = speedupfactor * delta0

# IrwinHall scaled and shifted as if the underlying uniform draw was over [-1,1]
randdraw = 2*IrwinHall(n=speedupfactor) - speedupfactor  
max_distance_possible = max_speed * delta0
current_position += max_distance_possible * randdraw

positions.append(current_position)
seconds.append(frame * delta)
```

If your process is truly continuous, then the limiting case of `delta0 = 0` means this will be equivalent to drawing from a purely normal distribution, and you can do that instead. This means you will have to define movement in terms of a standard deviation rather than a max speed.

Unfortunately scipy.stats does not have Irwin-Hall as a probability distribution, but it is implemented in sympy as [sympy.stats.UniformSum()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sympy-stats-uniformsum-in-python/)

Comment: Thanks, this is the kind of information I was looking for! I had understood why this was happening, but could not put it into words, nor figure out what kind of distribution I should be using instead. I especially appreciate your example of how to speed up the simulation by a given factor (which is exactly what I wanted to accomplish).

Comment: Happy to help out! Made some small clarifying edits in the last few minutes after you accepted the answer.

Comment: This would be a good thing to have more widely available, I've opened a feature request to add this (and the closely related Bates) distribution to scipy.stats: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/14806

Answer (score 3):

As you already know you are simulating different processes, which is why you obtain different behaviours.

A way of "rescaling" your curves is to plot the results in reduced units: divide the time (`x`) array by `delta` (which sets the timescale) and the position (`y`) array by `delta * max_speed` (which sets the lengthscale) to obtain something like this (note that I zoomed in to highlight the region of the plot where the overlap between the three sets of traces is a bit more visible):

[image: new plot]

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but (if I understood it correctly) this only changes the visual aspect of the plot afterwards - the values from the simulation itself are still "biased" by the `delta` parameter, so any posterior analysis will still carry this bias along with it. Feel free to correct me if I understood anything wrong.

Comment: You understood correctly, this answer is only squishing the graphics, not the data.